# pandas equivalent of R's cbind (concatenate/stack vectors vertically)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, concatenation, cbind

suppose I have two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

test1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5])

test2 = pd.DataFrame([4,2,1,3,7])
```

I tried `test1.append(test2)` but it is the equivalent of R's `rbind`.

How can I combine the two as two columns of a dataframe similar to the `cbind` function in R?

Comment: have you considered changing which answer is accepted? I think Feng Mai's answer is far more complete.

Comment: Sorry, I needed the answer in 2015, not in 2021 !!! Not fair to change the answer - particularly not fair to the person who responded to me 7 years ago when I needed the answer

Comment: I don’t like to go back 7 years ago. I appreciate you answering the question back then, but it’s no point in getting an answer 7 years later when I have long left Python for C# / Java and not interested in the answer anymore

Comment: @cphlewis: Feng Mai's more recent answer is more complete. On SO we might not change which answer got accepted, but we can upvote the better more recent answer. Also, this question really needs an MCVE. If the indices of test1 and test2 aren't identical, [`pd.concat()` causes issues due to always trying to align the misaligned axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801806/pandas-concat-columns-ignore-index-doesnt-work), unlike R's `cbind()`.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
test3 = pd.concat([test1, test2], axis=1)
test3.columns = ['a','b']
```

(But see the detailed answer by @feng-mai, below)

Comment: I did this, and it's adding rows, as if it's a join -- which is not what I want at all.

Comment: Is `axis=2` what you want?

Comment: Just for completeness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088010/pandas-column-bind-cbind-two-data-frames

Comment: axis = 0 is what you want.

Comment: @one_observation the answer from Feng Mai addresses this crucial issue and is superior, in my estimation as it more faithfully behaves like R cbind. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69874400/122792

Answer (score 18):

There is a key difference between `concat(axis = 1)` in pandas and `cbind()` in R:

`concat` **attempts to merge/align by index**. There is no concept of index in a R dataframe. If the two pandas dataframes' indexes are misaligned, the results are different from cbind (even if they have the same number of rows). You need to either make sure the indexes align or drop/reset the indexes.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

test1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5])
test1.index = ['a','b','c','d','e']
test2 = pd.DataFrame([4,2,1,3,7])
test2.index = ['d','e','f','g','h']

pd.concat([test1, test2], axis=1)

     0    0
a  1.0  NaN
b  2.0  NaN
c  3.0  NaN
d  4.0  4.0
e  5.0  2.0
f  NaN  1.0
g  NaN  3.0
h  NaN  7.0

pd.concat([test1.reset_index(drop=True), test2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  2
2  3  1
3  4  3
4  5  7

pd.concat([test1.reset_index(), test2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)      

  index  0  0
0     a  1  4
1     b  2  2
2     c  3  1
3     d  4  3
4     e  5  7
```

Comment: This index issue is absolutely central and yours should for that reason be the accepted answer. Anybody coming from R, looking for cbind, will need to know this.