# pandas concat columns ignore_index doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am trying to column-bind dataframes (like R's `cbind()` does) and having issue with pandas `concat`, as `ignore_index=True` doesn't seem to work:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 2, 3, 4])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': ['A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'],
                    'C': ['C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7'],
                    'D2': ['D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7']},
                   index=[5, 6, 7, 3])
df1
#     A   B   D
# 0  A0  B0  D0
# 2  A1  B1  D1
# 3  A2  B2  D2
# 4  A3  B3  D3

df2
#    A1   C  D2
# 5  A4  C4  D4
# 6  A5  C5  D5
# 7  A6  C6  D6
# 3  A7  C7  D7

dfs = [df1, df2]
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, ignore_index=True)     
print df
```

and the result is

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    
0   A0   B0   D0  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2   A1   B1   D1  NaN  NaN  NaN    
3   A2   B2   D2   A7   C7   D7   
4   A3   B3   D3  NaN  NaN  NaN  
5  NaN  NaN  NaN   A4   C4   D4  
6  NaN  NaN  NaN   A5   C5   D5  
7  NaN  NaN  NaN   A6   C6   D6
```

Even if I reset index using

```
df1.reset_index()    
df2.reset_index()
```

and then try

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

it still produces the same result!

The expected result is a 6x4 dataframe where the contents of columns A,B,D, A1,C,D2 are horizontally concatenated.

Comment: Does `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)` produce what you want? If not, can you specify your expected output?

Comment: no, it binds the rows . I want to bind the columns (append). I tried append, that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @ajcr, have you compared the output of `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)` and `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`? Shouldn't the first intuitively emulate a `cbind`?

Comment: I think `ignore_index` only ignores the labels on the axis you're joining on, so it still does an outer join on the index labels. I agree the names of function arguments aren't the most intuitive here.

Comment: yes, i realized that from @Alex answer ... but i have the same results even with ignore_index=False

Answer (score 144, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you would like to do.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 2, 3, 4])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': ['A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'],
                    'C': ['C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7'],
                    'D2': ['D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7']},
                   index=[4, 5, 6 , 7])


df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Which gives:

```
    A   B   D   A1  C   D2
0   A0  B0  D0  A4  C4  D4
1   A1  B1  D1  A5  C5  D5
2   A2  B2  D2  A6  C6  D6
3   A3  B3  D3  A7  C7  D7
```

Actually, I would have expected that `df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, ignore_index=True)` gives the same result.

This is the excellent explanation from **jreback**:

> `ignore_index=True` ‘ignores’, meaning doesn’t align on the joining axis. it simply pastes them together in the order that they are passed, then reassigns a range for the actual index (e.g. `range(len(index))`)
> so the difference between joining on non-overlapping indexes (assume `axis=1` in the example), is that with `ignore_index=False` (the default), you get the concat of the indexes, and with `ignore_index=True` you get a range.

Comment: Oh that works ... Thanks!  Funny thing is I was using same method to bind dataframes inside a function and that was working fine! but one outside function wasn't

Comment: @mau, I have updated my answer and now use `pd.reset_index()`. I think this is a cleaner way.

Comment: I happened to try that out myself, could have saved myself few hours if i had seen this earlier :). Thanks...    `df = pd.concat( [df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)`

Answer (score 37):

The ignore_index option is working in your example, you just need to know that it is ignoring the *axis of concatenation* which in your case is the columns. (Perhaps a better name would be ignore_labels.) If you want the concatenation to ignore the index labels, then your axis variable has to be set to 0 (the default).

Comment: Thanks! that was helpful (can't upvote yet, low rep)

Comment: Indeed, this is a useful explanation that is missing in the docs.

Answer (score 26):

In case you want to retain the index of the left data frame, set the index of df2 to be df1 using `set_index`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2.set_index(df1.index)], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 8):

Agree with the comments, always best to post expected output.

Is this what you are seeking?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 2, 3, 4])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': ['A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'],
                    'C': ['C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7'],
                    'D2': ['D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7']},
                   index=[5, 6, 7, 3])

# Drop column names so we can concat()...
df1 = df1.transpose().reset_index(drop=True).transpose()
df2 = df2.transpose().reset_index(drop=True).transpose()

# Concatenate the dfs
dfs = [df1, df2]
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

print df

    0   1   2
0  A0  B0  D0
1  A1  B1  D1
2  A2  B2  D2
3  A3  B3  D3
4  A4  C4  D4
5  A5  C5  D5
6  A6  C6  D6
7  A7  C7  D7
```

Comment: Worth commenting that `df1.transpose().reset_index(drop=True).transpose()` or the more concise `df1.T.reset_index(drop=True).T` is simply a pandas idiom for "drop column names".

Answer (score 5):

You can use numpy's concatenate to achieve the result.

```
cols = df1.columns.to_list() + df2.columns.to_list()
dfs = [df1,df2]
df = np.concatenate(dfs, axis=1)  
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=cols)

Out[1]: 
    A   B   D  A1   C  D2
0  A0  B0  D0  A4  C4  D4
1  A1  B1  D1  A5  C5  D5
2  A2  B2  D2  A6  C6  D6
3  A3  B3  D3  A7  C7  D7
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `ignore_index=True` doesn't help in my case.
I wanted to keep index from the first dataset and ignore the second index. This worked for me:

```
X_train = pd.concat([train_sp, X_train.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)], axis=1)
```

Comment: `inplace=True`? That shouldn't be there, it'll make it return `None`.