# Pandas Concat increases number of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, concatenation

I'm concatenating two dataframes, so I want to one dataframe is located to another.
But first I did some transformation to initial dataframe:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler() 
real_data = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df[real_columns]), columns = real_columns)
```

And then concatenate:

```
categorial_data  = pd.get_dummies(df[categor_columns], prefix_sep= '__')
train = pd.concat([real_data, categorial_data], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

I dont know why, but number of rows increased:

```
print(df.shape, real_data.shape, categorial_data.shape, train.shape)
(1700645, 23) (1700645, 16) (1700645, 130) (1703915, 146)
```

What happened and how fix the problem?

As you can see number of columns for train equals to sum of columns real_data and categorial_data

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801806/pandas-concat-ignore-index-doesnt-work and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250228/is-there-a-way-to-horizontally-concatenate-dataframes-of-same-length-while-ignor

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is that sometimes when you perform several operations on a single dataframe object, the **index persists in the memory**. So using **df.reset_index()** will solve your problem.

Comment: Ran in the same issue, to add a precision, use the df.reset_index() method on the dataframe you want to concatenate together, not on the resulting dataframe.

Answer (score 14):

While Performing some operations on a dataframe, its dimensions change not the indices, hence we need to perform `reset_index` operation on the dataframe.

For concatenation you can do like this:

```
result_df = pd.concat([first_df.reset_index(drop=True), second_df.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by using `hstack`

```
train = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([real_data,categorial_data]))
```

Comment: This way you lose all the dataframe information (e.g column names, index)

Comment: @Tonca How can I retain all the dataframe info?

Comment: In this case the columns are easy to keep because they remain the same as the original dataframes.
The problem comes  with the index. If the `concat` gives back a different number of rows (as explained in the question), it means that the indices of the DFs are not identical. I think it should be better to understand why are they different instead of forcing the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the indices of dataframes being concatenated differ. After preprocessing, the index of the resultant dataframe gets removed.  Setting the index of each dataframe back to the original works i.e. `df_concatenated.index = df_original.index`.