# pd.concat returning more rows that in the base dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a dataframe using columns from two different dataframes. I was using pd.concat but that was returning more than actual number of rows.

Although if I create dataframe by stacking the columns first in numpy array then I am getting expected result.

```py
print(df1.shape)
print(df2.shape)
result1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
result2 = pd.Dataframe(np.column_stack([df1.user_id, df2.prob]), 
columns = ["user_id", "prob"])
print(result1.shape)
print(result2.shape)
```

Output:

```
(221471, 1)
(221471, 1)
(221515, 2)
(221471, 2)
```

Can anyone please help me understand why concat is returning more number of rows?

Comment: Looks like an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368145/pandas-concat-increases-number-of-rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Concat increases number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368145/pandas-concat-increases-number-of-rows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the linked answer that the comments point to, is not complete. You need to use, exactly before the concat operation:

`df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
 df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

as seen in [pandas concat ignore_index doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32802014/6599916). I would comment the answer but I haven't got enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

after reset index use the following.

pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)