# How can I merge data frames by using the indexing of one of them?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames (A and B) as following:

*The types are:

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` ---> A

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` ---> B

A:

```
         target
145        1
557        1
240        1
893        1
1518       0
1145       0
```

B:

```
      RF  LR  NB  DT  SVM  Knn  SUM
0     1   0   0   1    1    1    4
1     1   1   1   1    0    1    5
2     1   1   1   1    1    1    6
3     1   1   1   1    1    1    6
4     1   0   0   1    0    0    2
5     1   1   1   0    1    1    5
```

I need one data frame that will include both.

How can I merge them together (by columns) by using the indexing of A (and ignore the indexing of B) ?

Comment: The title of your question exactly explains your intent, did you find anything from searching around this topic? What went wrong with the solutions you found?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801806/pandas-concat-ignore-index-doesnt-work) is relevant. Reset the index of both then join?

Comment: It get wrong. A lot of 'Na's in the combined table, which indicates that A and B were not match properly.

Comment: Could you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can drop the index from `A`, `join` or `concat` the two frames, and reset the index to be `A`'s index:

```
A.reset_index(drop=True).join(B).set_index(A.index)
# or
pd.concat((A.reset_index(drop=True), B),axis=1).set_index(A.index)

      target  RF  LR  NB  DT  SVM  Knn  SUM
145        1   1   0   0   1    1    1    4
557        1   1   1   1   1    0    1    5
240        1   1   1   1   1    1    1    6
893        1   1   1   1   1    1    1    6
1518       0   1   0   0   1    0    0    2
1145       0   1   1   1   0    1    1    5
```