# Joining two dataframes on index creates null values

Tags: python, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes which has non null values df1 and df2. Shape of df1 is (3681031, 52) and df2 is (3681031, 2). I'm concatenating the two dataframes using the following

```
df_merged = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)
```

I would expect the shape of the resulting dataframe to be (3681031, 54) however, it is (4667215, 54) and it also has a lot of nulls. Not sure whats going wrong as both the dataframes are sliced from the same dataframe.

I would appreciate any inputs.

Comment: There might possibly be duplicates, etc.

Comment: No they do not contain duplicates as the 2 columns in df2 are categorical and df1 contains only continuous variables.

Comment: Tried adding ignore_index=True to the concat command?

Comment: Also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32802014/9987623)

Comment: @AlexK : pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True) results in df of shape (7362062, 54)

Comment: axis=1 should remain.  And that link I provided should help you.

Comment: @AlexK - that worked, thanks