# Pandas column bind (cbind) two data frames

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I've got a dataframe `df_a` with id information:

```
    unique_id lacet_number
15    5570613  TLA-0138365
24    5025490  EMP-0138757
36    4354431  DXN-0025343
```

and another dataframe `df_b`, with the same number of rows that I know correspond to the rows in `df_a`:

```
     latitude  longitude
0  -93.193560  31.217029
1  -93.948082  35.360874
2 -103.131508  37.787609
```

What I want to do is simply concatenate the two horizontally (similar to `cbind` in R) and get:

```
    unique_id lacet_number      latitude  longitude
0     5570613  TLA-0138365    -93.193560  31.217029
1     5025490  EMP-0138757    -93.948082  35.360874
2     4354431  DXN-0025343   -103.131508  37.787609
```

What I have tried:

```py
df_c = pd.concat([df_a, df_b], axis=1)
```

which gives me an outer join.

```
    unique_id lacet_number    latitude  longitude
0         NaN          NaN  -93.193560  31.217029
1         NaN          NaN  -93.948082  35.360874
2         NaN          NaN -103.131508  37.787609
15    5570613  TLA-0138365         NaN        NaN
24    5025490  EMP-0138757         NaN        NaN
36    4354431  DXN-0025343         NaN        NaN
```

The problem is that the indices for the two dataframes do not match. I read the documentation for [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), and saw that there is an option `ignore_index`. But that only applies to the concatenation axis, in my case the columns and it certainly is not the right choice for me. So my question is: is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Should mention that [`cbind()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cbind.html) is an R function that concatenates dataframes and/or series ('vectors'), by column (`pd.concat(..., axis=1)`). However pandas `concat()` tries to align indices, whereas R's `cbind()` ignores them.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

If you're sure the index row values are the same then to avoid the index alignment order then just call [`reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index), this will reset your index values back to start from `0`:

```
df_c = pd.concat([df_a.reset_index(drop=True), df_b], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 5):

### [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

While `concat` is fine, it's simpler to [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
C = A.join(B)
```

This still assumes aligned indexes, so [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) as needed. In OP's example, `B`'s index is already default, so we only need to reset `A`:

```
C = A.reset_index(drop=True).join(B)

#    unique_id  lacet_number     latitude  longitude
# 0    5570613   TLA-0138365   -93.193560  31.217029
# 1    5025490   EMP-0138757   -93.948082  35.360874
# 2    4354431   DXN-0025343  -103.131508  37.787609
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set_axis` to make the index labels of one of the frames to be the same as the other's and concatenate horizontally or join. Unlike `reset_index`, this method preserves the index labels of one of the dataframes.

```py
joined_df = pd.concat([df_a.set_axis(df_b.index), df_b], axis=1)
# or using `join`
joined_df = df_a.set_axis(df_b.index).join(df_b)
```

[image: res]